# Posting different screenshots based on country - iTunes Connect/AppStore

Tags: iphone, app-store, app-store-connect

Since I'm not using any real localization technique besides having my dates generated based on the user's locale, I still wanted to have different screenshots in different countries for my app. Any way of doing this?

For reference, i know the app Moneybook is doing it, but also understand that they have localization support.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, within iTunes Connect add some localisation which allows for different text and images for languages.

If you just want different images you will need to copy your English text and keywords in.

Comment: It seems to support only language, instead of country. Is there anyway to customize the screenshot for US, UK, AU, NZ, etc? I could create UK, AU and UK but couldn't find NZ. I believe this also depends on iPhone Language. Is there anyway to customize for Region?

Comment: @JonasT could you find a way to do it.One approach could uploading different apps but that is too much overhead considering the upload/review process.